# Pillow was built without XCB support error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am coding in an Android device using an app called Pydroid3.
I want to use ImageGrab from pillow to take screenshots,I created a python file which takes screenshots using ImageGrab,but when I import it to other python file it shows error "Pillow was built without XCB support".
I imported everything from that file.

How could I resolve it

Comment: I have the same problem as you, and I hope this will help you.
[Another answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61537007/pillow-was-built-without-xcb-support)